# How to split a string using REGEX by keeping the sting within quote unaffected

Tags: regex, split, quote

I have a string:

```
((( OneAmount + ( OtherAmount / 20 ) ) * 100 ) - thirdAmount) where Status = 'Proposal / Price quote'
```

At present I am splitting it using this pattern:

```
(?<=[\\s+-+*/()])|(?<=(\'.[^-+*/()]\'))
```

Which gives me all the elements including the `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `(`, `)` characters and I need them. Now the problem is it is also splitting the string in single quote which is `'Proposal / Price quote'` which I do not want. How do I avoid this. There could be `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `(`, `)` anything in quotes.

How I can update my regular expression to handle such cases?
Edit:
Programming language: Java

**Expression used:**
( Priority='H+-*/()igh' AND ClosedDate=='10/11/2013' )

**Current output:**
(

Priority='H

### +

*
/
(
)
igh'

AND

ClosedDate=='10
/
11
/
2013'

)

**Expected output**
(

Priority='H+-*/()igh'

AND

ClosedDate=='10/11/2013'

)

Comment: Regular expressions are not good at handling recursive structures (e.g. parentheses within parentheses). Some regex engines have extensions to support recursion, but they are generally very difficult to use and aren't portable. You probably need proper parser instead.

Comment: I am using Split() to split the string.

Comment: Thanks p.s.w.g. I am using my own parser for handling recursion. I am  using split() and regex to split the string and then parsing it. I just want my regex not to split whatever inside the quotes.

Comment: Please update your question to include the following information: 1) What language / platform you're using, 2) Exactly what the current output is, 3) Exactly what the desired output is. Also be sure to use code blocks where appropriate.

Comment: Try something like `(?<=[-+*\\s/()])(?=(?:[^']|'[^']*')*$)` [test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oP2sW4/2) (checking if there's any amount of balanced quotes ahead). Also note, that your current regex  `+-+` in the character class is specifiying a faulty range, changed that.

Comment: You are probably not going to be able to do this with java's split. Why not just use a regular expression instead, to match what you want.